# How to use Groovy-Eclipse with specific groovy compiler?

Tags: groovy, groovy-eclipse

According to groovy-eclipse plug-in [website](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin), groovy-eclipse plug-in supports certain groovy versions, 1.8, 2.0 and 2.1. This seemed a bit restrictive to me. What am I supposed to do if I work with groovy 1.9 or 1.7?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the answer is that if you worked with Eclipse or GGTS before, then that couldn't happen; I suspect they never supported 1.9 or 1.7.

What is your concern?  If you're worried that you might start off with 2.1 and have it not supported in future, then don't worry.  If you're expecting to use some bizarre compiler feature that only worked in 1.9, then edit with the eclipse plugin for any version, and run Groovy (or Grails) from the command line with the right configuration.

Hope this helps...

- Charles

Answer (score 0):

Groovy-Eclipse supports the last couple of versions of groovy so we don't get into a maintenance headache. There is no Groovy 1.9 so we support right now 2.2/2.1/2.0/1.8 - we dropped 1.7. If you want to use 1.7 you would use an older version of groovy-eclipse that supported it. See version 2.8.0: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy-Eclipse+2.8.0+New+and+Noteworthy - on that page you can download an update site archive that will give you groovy-eclipse and groovy 1.7.10